# Projective module vs. Free module: dual basis lemma

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, projective-module

I am trying to understand definition (characterization) of projective module via dual basis lemma, compared with free module.

> Let $F$ be a left $R$-module.
>
> $F$ is said to be free if
>
> (1) there is a generating set $(u_i)$ of $F$;
>
> (2)  there is a family $f_i$ of $R$-homomorphisms from $F$ to $R$ with following property:
>
> (2.1) Every $x\in F$ can be written as $x=\sum_i f_i(x)u_i$, where all except finitely many $f_i(x)$ are $0$;
>
> (2.2) The expression in $(2.1)$ is unique.

**Q.** *The characterization of projective $R$-module via dual basis lemma can be obtained by dropping condition (2.2) in above definition.* Is this assertion correct?

I mean *$F$ is projective if and only if $(1)+(2)+(2.1)$ holds.*

Comment: Does the quoted characterization for free modules hold for non-finitely generated modules even if $R$ is a field?